# using ajax for comment form, it gives me 500 internal error but without script it works which means my script is wrong;right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have commenting system that works(at least works in the backend). The problem is every time user submits comment the page gets refreshed. I wrote an ajax function for this, but since I'm a beginner I was expecting to get an error and I did. I got 500 internal error.I'm not sure what I did wrong though. Here;s my code

```
<div class='reply_comment'>
        <form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='post_id' id='post_id' value='{% url "comment_create" %}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='origin_path' id='origin_path' value='{{ comment.get_origin }}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
        {% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}

        </form>
        </div>



<script>
 $(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/comment/create',
    data:{
      post_id:$('#post_id').val(),
      origin_path:$('origin_path').val(),
      parent_id:$('#parent_id').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success:function(){
      alert('it worked');
    }
  })

 })
</script>
```

I have url like this

```
   url(r'^comment/create/$', 'comment_create_view', name='comment_create'),
```

Edit:

I didn't post my views.py because it's huge, and thought I wrote ajax wrong. I'll post my view

```
def comment_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            post = None

        parent_comment = None
        if parent_id is not None:
            try:
                parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            except:
                parent_comment = None

            if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
                post = parent_comment.post

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            if parent_comment is not None:
                # parent comments exists
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post,
                    parent=parent_comment
                    )
                #affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()
                #print "this is"
                affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()

                return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
            else:
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=origin_path, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post
                    )
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            messages.error(request, "There was an error with your comment.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(origin_path)

    else:
        raise Http404
```

I forgot to add this here

```
urlpatterns += patterns('comments.views',
```

Edit two,
the reason I'm using class for commentForAjax rather than id is because I want to have same effect for my reply-comment code too. I want one ajax function for both of my forms.

```
<div class="make_reply">
    <a href='#' class='reply_btn'>reply</a>
        <div class='reply_comment'>
        <form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='post_id' id='post_id' value='{% url "comment_create" %}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='origin_path' id='origin_path' value='{{ comment.get_origin }}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
        {% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}

        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit:
here's my django error, I didn't know how to do it but followed daniel's guidance. is this the one?
RuntimeError at /comment/create
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/comment/create/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment/create
Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Executable: env/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path: [ 'env/lib/python2.7', 'env/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 'env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 'env/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 'env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 'env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 'env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time: í™”ìš”ì¼, 15 3ì›” 2016 18:48:14 +0900
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'comments',
 'notifications',
 'news',
 'tastypie',
 'userena',
 'guardian',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'accounts',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_select2',
 'actstream',
 'annoying',
 'embed_video',
 'ckeditor',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'whoosh',
 'haystack')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  108.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  84.                     "settings.") % (new_url[0], new_url[1]))

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /comment/create
Exception Value: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/comment/create/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
Request information:
GET: No GET data

POST:
post_id = u'/comment/create/'
csrfmiddlewaretoken = u'gw8ohxs2ZPVonPf812iM3vCAK2NnxAde'
parent_id = u'216'

FILES: No FILES data
```

Comment: post your view code.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I editted, any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You'll also need to show the actual Django error. You can find it in your browser's dev tools in the Network tab - click on the Ajax request.

Comment: Why do you set `post_id` to an url in your form? `<input type='hidden' name='post_id' id='post_id' value='{% url "comment_create" %}'/>`

Comment: @ilse2005 because comment for each post happens in comment_create

Comment: add a trailing slash to your url the ajax call --> `/comment/create/`

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask another question. Create a new on instead.

Comment: @ilse2005 oh sorry someone told me I should edit the question instead of creating one

Comment: the error tells you exactly what is wrong (your url ends with a slash but you posted to the url without the slash) ...the reason this is a problem is Django is configured to automatically redirect from `/myurl` to `/myurl/` ...but it can't do a redirect of a POST request, so it has to raise this exception for you (if Django wasn't configured to redirect you would get a 404 not found instead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception you posted is quite informative:

> Exception Value: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/comment/create/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
>   Request information:

So you have to add a trailing slash to your url in the ajax method:

```
<script>
 $(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/comment/create/',  //ADD THE SLASH!
    data:{
      post_id:$('#post_id').val(),
      origin_path:$('origin_path').val(),
      parent_id:$('#parent_id').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success:function(){
      alert('it worked');
    }
  })

 })
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much but I get 404 Page not found with this, I must put wrong url..hmm

Comment: What is the value of `{% url "comment_create" %}`? Print it somewhere in your template.

Comment: I couldn't print that in html it just prints {% url "comment_create" %}, it's just a url that does views.comment_create_view

Comment: by fixing  origin_path:$('#origin_path').val(), it shows it worked but how do I make the commenting works instead of it worked??

Comment: I was expecting comment to be displayed with it worked message but the comment is not being displayed, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: If you get an alert with `it worked` you're code is running. Where would you excpet the comment to display? There is nothing like that in your code

Comment: If you want to display the comment, then you have to modify your `success` function.

Comment: hmm how...that's the problem because without script file everything wors...ofc page gets refreshed everytime

Comment: Yes, because you have a pagereload without ajax. And django will do that for you. But without refresh you have to add the comment to the html by yourself.

Comment: and that's where ajax comes into play I believe, hmm can I create a new question asking what I should do in success function?

Answer (score 4):

There is something wrong in your script.

```
<script>
    ...
    origin_path:$('origin_path').val(),
    ...
</script>
```

origin_path is an id not a tag. Replace by this

```
<script>
    ...
    origin_path:$('#origin_path').val(),
    ...
</script>
```

For more help you should print the server error message

Comment: by fixing  origin_path:$('#origin_path').val(), it shows it worked but how do I make the commenting works instead of it worked??

Comment: I was expecting comment to be displayed with it worked message but the comment is not being displayed, do you know how to fix this?